# Increased number of "Timeout::Error: execution expired" errors in Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout

A couple months back I finally upgraded a Rails app on Heroku to the Cedar stack and Rails 3.2. Since it was suggested in the Cedar documentation, I created an initializer with this one line `Rack::Timeout.timeout = 20`. Everything worked fine for a long time, but in the past week I've suddenly begun getting numerous `Timeout::Error: execution expired` errors and associated `NoMethodError: undefined method 'result' for #<Timeout::Error: execution expired>` errors.

All of the errors are in mundane parts of the site that display basic content from the database, there's no interactive action going on that could take anywhere close to 20 seconds to process under normal conditions.

Is this the kind of thing that happens when traffic increases to the point where I need more dynos? Any advice you can give as to the source of these mysterious errors would be appreciated.

A few recent changes that I made to the site:

- Upgraded from Heroku Dev db to Heroku Basic db
- Explicitly defined the Ruby version in my gemfile `ruby '1.9.2'`
- Added IronWorker (from iron.io) to do some background tasks (for admins only, not the everyday users who are seeing the errors) I'm setting it up in `config/application.rb` with the following line: `config.iw_client = IronWorkerNG::Client.new(:token => iw_conf['iron']['token'], :project_id => iw_conf['iron']['project_id'])`

**Update:** I checked New Relic, and there's an extreme issue with the Heroku Basic DB performance.  Over the past 24 hours, the database response time has hovered towards the higher end of 1000ms to 6000ms. Is this an error on my part, or is it an issue with Heroku?

Comment: How does New Relic look? How busy is the site? How many dynos are you using?

Comment: New Relic says there is a problem with extreme database response time. It's averaging 1000ms to 6000ms per request over the last 24 hours.